# Export MySQL Data to a CSV file using PHP is displaying 1 row and blank CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I have this code that exports MySQL data to a CSV file but it is only displaying 1 row from the database when i echo out the results even though if i run the SQL in PHP My Admin it displays about 29 rows.

And it is just producing a blank CSV file

```
$sql="select description, jobreceived, timebookedfor, bookedfor,
      site_contact, site_address, invoice_contact, invoice_address,
      quotedprice, cleardowndetails, notes, mo_number from jobs ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$filename="jobs.csv";
$file=fopen($filename,"w");
//$output="sequence,firstname,surname,email,membertype\n";
fwrite($file,$output);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo $result["description"].','.$result["jobreceived"].'<br>';
    //$output=$result["sequence"].",".$result["name"].","
              .$result["email"].",".$result["country"]."\n";
    $output=proper($result["description"]).",".$result["jobreceived"]
           ."\r\n";
    fwrite($file,$output);
}
fclose($file);
function proper($string)
{
    $first=strtoupper(substr($string,0,1));
    $rest=strtolower(substr($string,1));
    $result=$first.$rest;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Start by using PHP's built-in fputcsv() function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: what error logs? i tried using the fputcsv instead of fopen but still nothing

Comment: Do you have write access to the directory and jobs.csv file? (you say its blank, so I assume it already exists) you should check this by `if(!$file) echo 'cannot open jobs.csv for writing';`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with these two functions

```
function csv_from_result($query, $delim = ",", $newline = "\n", $enclosure = '"')
{
    if ( ! is_object($query) OR ! method_exists($query, 'list_fields'))
    {
        show_error('You must submit a valid result object');
    }

    $out = '';

    // First generate the headings from the table column names
    foreach ($query->list_fields() as $name)
    {
        $out .= $enclosure.str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure.$enclosure, $name).$enclosure.$delim;
    }

    $out = rtrim($out);
    $out .= $newline;

    // Next blast through the result array and build out the rows
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        foreach ($row as $item)
        {
            $out .= $enclosure.str_replace($enclosure, $enclosure.$enclosure, $item).$enclosure.$delim;
        }
        $out = rtrim($out);
        $out .= $newline;
    }

    return $out;
}

function write_file($path, $data, $mode = 'wb')
{
    if ( ! $fp = @fopen($path, $mode))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Pass your query object to the function.

```
$sql="select
          description,
          jobreceived,
          timebookedfor,
          bookedfor,
          site_contact,
          site_address,
          invoice_contact,
          invoice_address,
          quotedprice,
          cleardowndetails,
          notes,
          mo_number
        from jobs";
$rs =   mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

now Pass the resource to the `csv_from_result` function

```
$file_data  =   csv_from_result($rs);
```

And now you can write file

```
$filename   =   "jobs.csv"; 
write_file($filename , $file_data); // $filename can be a complete path
```

Or echo to see csv result

```
echo $file_data;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please quote your sources when using code written by other authors?

Comment: Why write your own functions to create CSV formatted output when PHP has far superior built-in functions to do the job for you?

Comment: Yes sure these two functions are available in Great PHP framework called `Codeigniter`

Comment: excel will interpret 0001 as 1, so fputcsv is NOT as superior as you think. '0001' is a string

Comment: well this functions has some checks and it handles the error properly. One does not want any undesired errors on his screen. And this is work for once only. Next time you will simply use it as functions ARE for this purpose.

Comment: @raheel - use fputcsv() or the SplFileObject fputcsv() method - they're built into PHP itself

Comment: @Waygood - fputcsv() works correctly if you write 0001, it's MS Excel that chooses to interpret it as a number rather than adhere to the (admittedly variable) CSV standard

Comment: Everyone stop using Excel. Mark has spoken (LOL) These functions are far more flexible

Comment: @Waygood - There are ways of tricking MS EXcel into treating 0001 as a string (e.g "=0001"), but CSV is not a well-defined standard and open to interpretation; but MS EXcel will always reformat numeric values as numbers - if you want to control formatting of data values, then CSV isn't a good option. You're saying fputcsv() is wrong, when it's MS EXcel that's wrong - that's what I'm defending; especially when the alternative is a "homebrew" that suffers exactly the same problem with MS EXcel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try removing fwrite($file,$output); statement from your loop. If the query results are echoed as expected then the problem is obviously the fwrite statement (maybe file permission). 
If the results are not echoed as expected then there could be an issue with your query results. 
Furthermore, as a suggestion, make sure that you use the correct line-ending characters for your operating system, as the fopen manual dictates.